# Configuring rsnapshot to only daily backups

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I configured rsnapshot so it would not backup hourly by commenting out the hourly cronjob in `/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot`:

```
#0 */4          * * *           root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
30 3    * * *           root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
0  3    * * 1           root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
30 2    1 * *           root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly
```

But this gives the error:

```
/.snapshots/hourly.5 not present (yet), nothing to copy
```

And it doesn't backup anything any more ever since.

As a workaround, I called this manually now once:

```
/usr/bin/rsnapshot -v hourly
```

But how do I configure this correctly so backups only are done once a day at 3:30 am?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the cron job is not enough. You also have to adapt the config file to reflect the change. Remove (or uncomment) the following line from `/etc/rsnapshot.conf`:

```
retain  hourly  24
```

Then your backups should work again.

Comment: I have no `retain`, still `interval`, but you are right, the new name is 'retain', see http://sourceforge.net/p/rsnapshot/mailman/message/6585583

Comment: @rubo77 Then you have a really old version of `rsnapshot` or use are using deprecated syntax. For details about your particular version you can check the man page: `man rsnapshot | less -p 'retain|interval'`